# How to know all bases and exponents of a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, pow

I want to find all bases and exponents of a number.

Example:

```
Number = 64
2^6=64
4^3=64
8^2=64
64^1=64

Number = 1845.28125
4.5^5=1845.28125

Number = 19683
3^9=19683
27^3=19683
19683^1=19683
```

What I do now is to make an integer of 'Number' and just see of the results of multiple calculations gives the correct result:

```
basehits, expohits = [], []

if eval(Number) > 1000:
   to = 1000   #base max 1000 in order to avoid too many calculations
else:
   to = int(eval(Number))

for n in range(1,to):
  for s in range(1,31): #just try with exponents from 1 to 30
    calcres = pow(n,s)
    if calcres == eval(Number):
       basehits.append(n)
       expohits.append(s)
    elif calcres > eval(Number):
       break
```

The problem is that this never find a Floating Number as for example `1845.28125` (see above).
Is there a better way to find exponents and bases when only the result is known?

Comment: Don't use `eval`. Use `int` instead.

Comment: `eval` and `exec` should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
import math    
num=64
for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
    if math.log(num,i).is_integer():
        print i,int(math.log(num,i))
```

the output is:

```
2 6
4 3
8 2
```

and of course, you can always add:

```
print num,1
```

to get

```
64,1
```

If you want to add fractions, with n decimal digits after the dot, you can use this:

```
from __future__ import division
import math



num=1845.28125
decimal_digits=1
ans=3
x=1
while(ans>=2):
    ans=num**(1/x)
    if (ans*10**decimal_digits).is_integer():
        print ans,x
    x+=1
```

where `decimal_digits` indicates the number of places after the dot.

For this example the answer will be

`4.5 5`,

If you change for example `num` to `39.0625` and `decimal_digits` to 2, the output will be:

`2.5 4
6.25 2`

Comment: Great solution beniev. It still doesn't find the 2nd number but your solution is much much nicer than the one I have.

Comment: It is a step in the right direction, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem needs more constraints, but here's some help:

```
>>> from math import log
>>> help(log)
Help on built-in function log in module math:

log(...)
    log(x[, base])

    Return the logarithm of x to the given base.
    If the base not specified, returns the natural logarithm (base e) of x.

>>> for base in range(2, 10):
...     exp = log(64, base)
...     print('%s ^ %s = %s' % (base, exp, base ** exp))
...     
2 ^ 6.0 = 64.0
3 ^ 3.785578521428744 = 63.99999999999994
4 ^ 3.0 = 64.0
5 ^ 2.5840593484403582 = 63.99999999999999
6 ^ 2.3211168434072493 = 63.99999999999998
7 ^ 2.1372431226481328 = 63.999999999999964
8 ^ 2.0 = 64.0
9 ^ 1.892789260714372 = 63.99999999999994
```

Answer (score 1):

## Integers

For integers you could look at the [prime factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor) of your number. Once you know that 64 is `2**6`, it's easy to list all the results you wanted.

Now, which result do you expect for numbers that have at least 2 different prime factors? For example : should 15 be written `3*5`, `3**1 * 5**1` or `15**1`?

## Floats

It's not clear how your problem is defined for Floats.

What's special about `4.5`?
If you calculate `1845.28125**(1.0/5)`, Python returns `4.5`, but for other input numbers, the result might be off by 1e-16.

## Possible solution

```
import math

def find_possible_bases(num, min_base = 1.9, max_decimals = 9, max_diff = 1e-15):
  max_exponent = int(math.ceil(math.log(num,min_base)))
  for exp in range(1,max_exponent):
    base = round(num**(1.0/exp),max_decimals)
    diff = abs(base**exp-num)
    if diff < max_diff:
      print('%.10g ** %d = %.10g' % (base, exp, base ** exp))

find_possible_bases(64)
# 64 ** 1 = 64
# 8 ** 2 = 64
# 4 ** 3 = 64
# 2 ** 6 = 64

find_possible_bases(19683)
# 19683 ** 1 = 19683
# 27 ** 3 = 19683
# 3 ** 9 = 19683

find_possible_bases(1845.28125)
# 1845.28 ** 1 = 1845.28
# 4.5 ** 5 = 1845.28

find_possible_bases(15)
#  15 ** 1 = 15
```

It iterates over possible exponents, and calculates what the base would be. It rounds it to 9 decimals, and checks what the error becomes. If it's small enough, it displays the result. You could play with the parameters and find what best suits your problem.
As a bonus, it also works fine with Integers (e.g. 64 and 15).

It might be better to work with [Rational numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html).